# Code executing only one function regardless of if else statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, arduino

I'm making an Arduino robot, which is a simple line-following robot, but if I press a button on an IR remote, it continues to line follow, but at a different speed. Here's the code that I've written:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
const int RECV_PIN = A5;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
int cs;         // CENTER SENSOR
int lmt1 = 5;   // LEFT MOTOR 1
int lmt2 = 3;   // LEFT MOTOR 2
int rmt1 = 6;   // RIGHT MOTOR 1
int rmt2 = 11;  // RIGHT MOTOR 2

void setup() {
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(lmt1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lmt2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rmt1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rmt2, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() {
  {
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
      Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
      irrecv.resume();
    }
  }

  cs = digitalRead(8);

  if (cs == LOW) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 175);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 175);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 0);
  }
  if (cs == HIGH) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 175);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 175);
  }
  if ((results.value == 0xFE58A7) && (cs == HIGH)) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 100);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 0);
  }
  if ((results.value == 0xFE58A7) && (cs == LOW)) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 100);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 0);
  }
}
```

The robot follows the line, but already at a lower speed and the IR remote has no effect on the speed of the robot. I appreciate any help. (I've used an Arduino board and an L298N motor driver)

Comment: Please format your code properly, and specifically remove many unneeded empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Arduino, but I'm going to take a wild guess. This code

```
if (digitalRead(results.value == 0xFE58A7) && (cs == HIGH)) {
```

should be

```
if (digitalRead(results.value) == 0xFE58A7 && (cs == HIGH)) {
```

In other words you got your brackets in the wrong place.

Or perhaps you didn't mean to call `digitalRead` at all. Maybe this was the code you meant to write

```
if ((results.value == 0xFE58A7) && (cs == HIGH)) {
```

As I said I know nothing about Arduino, but your code looks odd.

You have the same error a few lines later.

Comment: or maybe its the `cs` from `cs = digitalRead(8);` they want to use in the condition

Comment: `digitalRead` can only return `LOW` or `HIGH` which is defined as `0x0` and `0x1` so to compare it with `0xFE58A7` will always be false. On the other hand `digitalRead` needs a pin which it will read as parameter (on an Arduino Uno 2-13 is valid). So both brackets won't work. The last suggestion looks good.

Comment: Well, I just realized this, and also changed the question, the bot is just running at a slower speed already. This has made things worse, as the bot's speed is set low regardless of the input from the remote.

Comment: Just changed the code based on everyone's advice, no luck yet.

Comment: @ShreyasTandon You need to debug, by printing out the values of the various variables you are interested in. Also put print statements in the various if statements so you know whether those are being executed or not. Only when you know more about how your program runs can you narrow down what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the changes from john you should use `else if`s:

```
  if (results.value == 0xFE58A7 && (cs == LOW)) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 100);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 0);
  } else if (results.value == 0xFE58A7 && (cs == HIGH)) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 100);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 0);
  } else if (cs == LOW) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 175);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 175);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 0);
  } else if (cs == HIGH) {
    analogWrite(lmt1, 175);
    analogWrite(lmt2, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt1, 0);
    analogWrite(rmt2, 175);
  }
```

The `loop()` function will repeat infinite times. If you only use `if`, each one that resolves to true will run. So in your case at least one will run, but if `results.value == 0xFE58A7` is true, two of your statements will be true and switch your pins at a very high speed.

The motor has a much slower reaction time and may behave weird or not at all.

To debug your code I recommend writing `Serial.println` in each if and a `delay(100)` at the end of the loop. With that you can actually see what your code is currently doing.

[Here is a small simulation](https://wokwi.com/projects/347751028405305938) similar to your example. You have a switch for your `cs` variable and can use the remote with the `1` key to jump into the first two statements. With any other key you get back.